# How to call a chrome API function from an injected function (through scripting.executeScript)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I injected a function through `scripting.executeScript` to recursively create buttons. I want the buttons to call a Chrome API function [(downloads.download)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/#method-download) once clicking. To generate the buttons, I did:

```
// background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        // intended to pass the below download function for it to be run later on <<
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tabId},
            func: addButtons,
            args: [download]
        })
    }
})

function addButtons(downloadCallback) {
    // get all current posts
    let posts = ...
    
    // add download button to all posts
    for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        ...
        let url = tryQuickUrl(post);
        ...

        let button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerText = "Download";
        
        // intended to use the callback to the download function below <<<<<
        button.onclick = function() { downloadCallback(url); };

        post.appendChild(button);
    }
}
```

The error here is that `download` can't be serialized, but if I try to use no arguments and attempt to call the function by `button.onclick = function() { download(url); };`, it gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: download is not defined`. If I try embedding the function into the anonymous function:

```
button.onclick = function() { chrome.downloads.download({ // error here
    url: url,
    filename: "test.jpg"
}); };
```

that gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'download')` (so you can't access API functions here?).

How would I call `chrome.downloads.download` from an injected script? Thanks!

Comment: Use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). The API will be used inside the background script's onMessage.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone sees this in the future, I just had to use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to pass messages between the extension and script. I used a listener to listen for incoming messages (from scripts), and handled them accordingly;

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension"
        );
        
        if (request.request === "downloadUrl") {
            let [result, response] = download(request.url);
            sendResponse({
                success: result,
                response: response,
            });
        }
    }
);
```

and sent a message upon button clicking.

```
button.onclick = function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    request: "downloadUrl",
    url: url,
  }, function(response) {
    console.log("WEEE", response.farewell);
  });
};
```